# How to wait on a callback to complete before proceeding

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm currently trying something in Node JS where I want a function with a callback to update a variable name and then I will log out the variable name.  Below describes what I am trying to acheive

```
var testVariable = "first"

functionWithCallbackWhichPopulatesTestVariableWithWordSecond(callback)

Print testVariable
```

In the above scenario when testVariable is output it is outputting "first" but I want it to be "second" as the callback function that is passed in should change it to "second".

Hopefully that makes sense.  I'm not sure I have explained it the best but would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell whether you've got a scoping problem (where `callback` doesn't see the right variable) or you don't understand how async works (the callback is being called after the print already happened).

Comment: You should add the actual code you're using rather than pseudocode which we can't debug. We have no idea, for example, what `callback` is doing. In it's simplest form [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/k1m27c98/).

Comment: Does either `functionWithCallbackWhichPopulatesTestVariableWithWordSecond()` or `callback()` contain asynchronous operations?

Comment: Thank you guys, I realize my question was poorly put together and had a severe lack of useful information.  I have reworded and created a JSFiddle representing the question in another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084810/getting-a-callback-to-wait-on-an-async-call